# How do i retrieve the progress of a native html form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm doing some front-end stuff for a Rails app and I don't get to mess with the backend architecture. Basically, I'm supposed to allow users to upload a file and make that submission essentially go straight to Amazon through a form handled by CarrierWave. If you've ever tried to do this same thing with ajax, you'll know it's virtually impossible.

That puts me here: I need to be able to call `.submit()` on an html form element and then hook into the progress of the upload as if I were listening for the "progress" event on an XMLHttpRequest.

Forgive me for not showing tons of code. I'm really just looking for two very simple things.

1. Is it possible to trap the form's native progress event?
2. If so, what's the basic technique? Is it something simple like `form.addEventListener('progress', function () {...})`? (<- That doesn't work, by the way.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you must send the progress information from the backend

Comment: @jlarson Does that imply there is no way to hook into the event unless I do it through ajax?

Comment: that's been my experience

Comment: If your form is doing a traditional `GET` or `POST` as the action on which you're waiting and wanting progress updates, then there is no event to hook into, as that would require the browser to inherently know what the back-end is doing with the `GET`/`POST` request in order to provide the event in the first place. This is impossible without the back-end sending back periodic information in some way via AJAX.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without hooking the `progress` event of an XmlHTTPRequest's `upload` propery. Since a form can combine an arbitrary number of inputs, I can't see how it could provide such a feature as a standard.

Comment: Thanks all. @ajp15243 It appears the browser (Chrome, at least) does have access to this info because it displays a native indicator at the bottom of the screen during long uploads. However, sadly, I believe you're all correct. The browser doesn't give you access to that information.

Comment: @rescuecreative Any indicator that Chrome displays when it comes to the processing that has been handed off to the server is only a best guess. Otherwise, it's taking into account the loading of assets like images and JS/CSS files.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can get progress on the upload on a standard form submit.

So I haven't tested this, but why not submit the form via AJAX? You can upload files with a `FormData` object, which can handle multipart requests for uploads.

Something like this might work:

```
// grab the form you want to submit.
var formElement = document.getElementById("myFormElement");

// make an xhr object
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// track progress
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);

// setup request method and url
request.open("POST", formElement.action);

// send the request
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

You would have to listen for the server response and do what it tells you, redirect or handle failures or whatever. But I think it should work. The server you are submitting to probably doesn't care if it's a xhr request or a standard browser request.

And it should work in [all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData)

---

[See docs on `FormData`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects)

[And here's a link to that details](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/) how to track progress on ajax uploads.

Comment: Thanks, yeah initially I thought that was impossible and in fact, due to my specific setup, this of itself isn't enough. I eventually found [this github comment](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/issues/99#issuecomment-24716251) describing a cool way of using jQuery.fileUpload that ended up working.